# focus event not working when i'm active in another tab of the browser (js | jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

i have an input element with `id='idtxt'` and i want to set the value on it include sign | of cursor,and i using `focus()` event to do that

> document.getElementById('idtxt').value = 'mytxt'; // mytxt|
>   document.getElementById('idtxt').focus();

but `focus()` just work if i'm active in this tab of browser, on the other hand ! it wrong if i'm active in another tab. i guess , when i'm in another tab, my cursor not available on the one which i want to handle insert text and sign |, and `focus()` not working.it hard to found this bug, cause if i'm back form another tab, the sign | is stand at the right position. so what i have to do to solve this problem ?

1. emulator an cursor in the tab i want to handle and focus() can be right work . why to do this ?
2. or insert an ascii charater look like sign | and ignore `focus()` or cursor have active in the tab, is it exist really solution ?
3. or any solution suggestion for me to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: How do you focus something in an inactive tab ?

Comment: @adeno so how can i active the tab if it needed ? i try using window.focus , but it not working too. pls help